# CMake does not link ncurses

Tags: cmake, ncurses

I am a total noob concerning CMake. My `CMakeLists.txt` is really basic:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#For the Curses library to load:
SET(CURSES_USE_NCURSES TRUE)

include_directories(
     "src/"
)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

When I make, the linker does not find the ncurses commands and in the verbose mode of make, I see that the compiler did not add the `-lncurses`. What do I have to add to the CMakeLists to make it work?

Comment: You should not set EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH relative to PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR as this makes it impossible to perform proper out-of-tree builds.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For the super noob, remember `target_link_libraries()` needs to be below `add_executable()`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8) project(main)

find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: I was using `Curses_INCLUDE_DIR` and `Curses_LIBRARIES` once I uppercased them, it worked

Answer (score 12):

before use some third party libs, you ought to find it!
in case of `ncurses` you need to add `find_package(Curses REQUIRED)` and then use `${CURSES_LIBRARIES}` in a call to `target_link_libraries()` and `target_include_directories(... ${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked!  For complete noobs it is target_link_libraries(your_exe ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})