# How to fix ncurses?

Tags: c++

I'm a mac user, and I'm using the XCode developer tools and using CLion as a compiler. When I try to use ncurses and its functions, specifically getch(), I get the following error.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_stdscr", referenced from:
>         _main in main.cpp.o
>     "_wgetch", referenced from:
>         _main in main.cpp.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

I've tried to go online and reinstall ncurses, but it hasn't fixed anything. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, CLion isn't a compiler. It's an IDEA (integrated development
environment). As I remember using it last time it uses CMake as a build tool. And CMake uses GCC, Clang, MSVC, whatever under the hood.

As you don't post any code sample I will try to guess the problem. Usually
when using ncurses you need to link with it as: `-lncurses`. For more info you
should look `man ncurses` on your platform. Also check that you don't forget to include the required header. E.g. on my system it's `#include <curses.h>`.

[How to link with ncurses via CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693381/cmake-does-non-link-ncurses)